# Select elements from an array using another array as index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an array

```
A = array([[1,2,3],
           [4,5,6],
           [7,8,9]])
```

Index array is

```
B = array([[1], # want [0, 1] element of A
           [0],  # want [1, 0], element of A
           [1]])  # want [2, 1] elemtn of A
```

By this index array `B`, I want a `3-by-1` array, whose elements are taken from array `A`, that is

```
C = array([[2],
           [4],
           [8]])
```

I tried `numpy.choose`, but I failed to that.

Answer (score 5):

For answer completeness... Fancy indexing arrays are broadcast to a common shape, so the following also works, and spares you that final reshape:

```
>>> A[np.arange(3)[:, None], B]
array([[2],
       [4],
       [8]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> A[np.arange(len(A)), B.ravel()].reshape(B.shape)
array([[2],
       [4],
       [8]])
```

Comment: Nice, why didn't I think of it, ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
>>>np.diag(A[range(3),B]).reshape(B.shape)
array([[2],
       [4],
       [8]])
```

If you want to use `choose` you can do: `np.choose(B.ravel(), A.T).reshape(B.shape)`.

Comment: Thanks for the trick, the doc of `choose` is hard for me to understand.